# with clause sql statement maximum limit in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, cte

```
 with s as (select         
            distinct  
                s.empno,
                s.deptnumber,
                s.age,
                s.salary
            from emp.employee details s )
select * from  s;
```

I am having above with clause subquery. Need to know the maximum number of rows limit for a with clause subquery in memory.

Using Oracle 12c 12.1

Comment: It depends on where you're selecting it to. If it's to a file, then the limit depends on the amount of filespace left. If you're retrieving it in a GUI (e.g. Toad, SQL Developer, etc) it depends on how much available RAM you have left. There is no limit placed on the results from Oracle; it will retrieve what you ask for - it's where you put it that limits things. The real question is: Why do you need to know this? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: And your error message is...

Comment: it is impossible to predict does Oracle will remain the result in memory, even when this result contains one record, or it will cache it to disk (of course, the probability of such an event is extremely small, but still more than zero)...

Comment: As you run `SELECT DISTINCT` Oracle has to sort the result, i.e. it is written into TEMP tablespace. So in fact, the limit is determined by the size of your TEMP tablespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum. Neither in a query result nor in a subquery or CTE.

If the table has a thousand rows, the query will return a thousand rows.
If it has a billion, it will return a billion rows. If it's a trillion, a trillion rows will be returned.

Whether the receiving application can handle so much data is another matter.